# How to consider the first value of a pandas dataframe filtering by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe:

[image: Dataframe i have]

I need to consider only the first "up" of the day.

So
My goal is to have this dataframe:

[image: Dataframe i want]

This is some working code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
tbl = {"date" :["2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-28", "2022-02-28","2022-02- 
      28"],
               "direction" : ["up", "up", "NaN", "NaN", "up", "up"]}



df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)
df = df.replace('NaN', float('nan'))
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.sort_values(by = "date", inplace=True)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mask` the `duplicated` values per `date` and `direction`:

```
df['direction'] = df['direction'].mask(df.duplicated(['date', 'direction']))
```

---

```
         date direction
0  2022-02-27        up
1  2022-02-27       NaN
2  2022-02-27       NaN
3  2022-02-28       NaN
4  2022-02-28        up
5  2022-02-28       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if i have multiple dates like this: '2022-02-27 08:00:00'  '2022-02-27 08:00:05', ? So with hours, minutes and seconds, and i need to consider only the first value of the day?

Comment: In that case `floor` the datetime column then use duplicated..`df['direction'].mask(df.assign(date=df['date'].dt.floor('d')).duplicated(['date', 'direction']))`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['direction']=df.assign(cnt=df.groupby(['date','direction']).cumcount()).apply(lambda row: row['direction'] if (row['cnt'] ==0) else np.nan, axis=1)
df
```

````
    date    direction
0   2022-02-27  up
1   2022-02-27  NaN
2   2022-02-27  NaN
3   2022-02-28  NaN
4   2022-02-28  up
5   2022-02-28  NaN```
````

Comment: Hello, I think you forgot to add the code

Comment: oops!, it was on same line as the ```  . its fixed now